# Diverts deleted when restarting ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have searched and haven't found anything about this online nor in the manual.

I have setup addresses and use both multicast to several queues and an AnyCast to a single queue (All durable queues). To this I have connected Diverts created in the API in runtime.

The diverts works great when sending messages. BUT when I restart the ActiveMQ Artemis instance the Diverts are deleted. Everything else is in place. Just the Diverts are deleted.

Any ideas on how to keep Diverts after a Restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diverts created via the management API during runtime are volatile. If you wish to have a divert which survives a broker restart you should modify the broker.xml with the desired divert configuration.

Of course, the current behavior may not work for your use-case. If that's true then I would encourage you to open a "Feature Request" JIRA at [Artemis JIRA project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS). Furthermore, if you're really committed to seeing the behavior change you can [download the code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis), make the necessary changes, and submit a pull-request (or attach a patch to the JIRA). Checkout the [Artemis Hacking Guide](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/hacking-guide/) for help getting started.

**Update**: The functionality to persist diverts added via the management API was added in 2.16.0 via [ARTEMIS-2908](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2908).

Comment: Thank you. Is this really a good solution? Why can't Diverts be like any other Durable Queues and be permanent? We were thinking like an extra backup and have rotating purges every 10 days.